# WSO2 APP Manager : ERROR - MDMOperationsImpl Error while getting the device list from WSO2 EMM

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-iot

I am running only WSO2 APP Manager and published an Android and iOS mobile apps, I don't want to use MDM and I want to download and install apps directly on devices through **WSO2 app manager's store without MDM/EMM integration.**

But when I try to tap the install button, it's showing that Select your device window with "Sorry you don't have devices to install this app" message

Please check my few configurations of app-manager.xml,

```
<Config name="IsCatalog">false</Config>
<!-- Enables app to download direcly to the mobile device from the App Manager without MDM -->  
<Config name="EnableDirectDownload">true</Config>

<Config name="EnableMDMOperations">false</Config>

<Config name="ActiveMDM">WSO2EMM</Config>
<Config name="EnableSelfUnsubscription">true</Config>
<Config name="EnableSubscriptionFromDevices">true</Config>
<Config name="EnableSampleDevices">false</Config>
<Config name="AppDownloadURLHost">%https%</Config>
<Config name="IosPlistPath">publisher/api/mobileapp/getplist</Config>
```

Kindly help me to setup a private mobile app store by opening the wso2 store and install apps on devices without WSO2-MDM.

Answer (score 0):

Change the value of EnableSubscriptionFromDevices to false.Only you need to EnableDirectDownload . check https://jenananthan.wordpress.com/2015/11/20/how-to-use-mobile-store-in-wso2-appmanager-without-mdm/

This seems to a bug https://wso2.org/jira/browse/APPM-1580.
As the woraround update the line[1] in the file /repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/store/extensions/assets/mobileapp/modules/mod-ent-install.js

as follow

```
var location = serverAddress + "/store/api/mobileapp/getfile/" +asset.attributes.overview_url;
```

1.https://github.com/wso2/carbon-appmgt/blob/master/features/org.wso2.carbon.appmgt.store.feature/src/main/resources/store/extensions/assets/mobileapp/modules/mod-ent-install.js#L140

Comment: Hi Jenananthan, Thank you very much for your response, Using WSO2 app manager 1.2.0, I have changed EnableSubscriptionFromDevices to false, now when I try to install an android app on an Android device, it prompt the confirmation saying "Are you sure you want to install this app?" when I click yes, it redirect to a blank page. Kindly help me.

Comment: For older browser, it redirects to a blank page, but new chrome browser it redirects to the same page.

Comment: @Loganathan It seems to be a bug https://wso2.org/jira/browse/APPM-1580.Update the answer with workaround